# "Alcuno" vs "nessuno" in negative sentences

Tags: difference, adjectives

What is the difference between using "alcuno" and "nessuno" in negative sentences? Are the sentences below correct? Is there a difference of meaning? Is one of them more usual?

- Lui non mangia carne.
- Lui non mangia alcuna carne.
- Lui non mangia nessuna carne.

Comment: Carne is, in English terminology, a mass noun, so you can’t use alcuna or nessuna before it

Comment: @egreg Sei così sicuro? *Non mangia nessuna carne: né manzo né maiale*.

Comment: I would say all these sentences are correct, but "Non mangia alcuna carne" (which is equivalent to "Non mangia nessuna carne") is less used nowadays. The meaning is similar, but "Non mangia nessuna carne" carries a slightly different nuance: it stresses on the fact that there are different kinds of meat and the subject of the sentence doesn't eat any of them.

Comment: @DenisNardin non mangia carne, né manzo né maiale

Comment: @egreg: Sul [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI02/GDLI_02_ocr_787.pdf) si trova "carni bianche", "carni rosse", "carni nere", "carni affumicate"...

Comment: @Charo could you create an answer with your explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these sentences are correct, but "Non mangia alcuna carne" (which is equivalent to "Non mangia nessuna carne") is less used nowadays, as you can see from this extract of a section talking about indefinite adjectives and pronouns from the book *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*, by Vittorio Coletti:

> Nell'italiano antico *alcuno* poteva essere usato anche al singolare in frasi positive, ma oggi non è più ammesso, e la nostra lingua tende a comportarsi come il francese (dove *aucun* si trova solo in frasi negative) e a differire dallo spagnolo e dal portoghese che conservano il valore positivo di *algún*. 
>         *Alcuno* al singolare patisce la concorrenza di *nessuno* (come in spagnolo) e stenta quindi, diversamente che in francese, anche in questo ruolo («non c'è nessuna traccia» è molto più attestato su Google di «non c'è alcuna traccia»).

The meaning of your sentences is similar, but "Non mangia nessuna carne" (or "alcuna carne") carries a slightly different nuance: it stresses on the fact that there are different kinds of meat and the subject of the sentence doesn't eat any of them.